# Regex to match alphanumerical strings for password and username

Tags: regex

I want to use regular expression for username and password. They should only contain:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890@-.#_
```

How I get this?

Comment: Please don't restrict the characters in passwords. There's no need.

Comment: +1 to @John Kugleman .  So tired of useless restrictions like this.

Answer (score 5):

`/[A-Za-z0-9@\'\-.#_]+/`.

To break it down:

1. the part inside `[...]` are the characters you want to match.
2. the `A-Z` is a character range with - separating the ends.
3. `\-` is a literal dash.
4. `+` means one or more.

Depending on how you match you might want to use `^` and `$` at the ends to ensure it matches the whole input (or `^` and `\Z` in Java & Perl5).

Comment: What if he wanted to allow the same characters and had a limit 0f 6 to 20 characters? This is my question but I think it's too trivial to be an actual question.

Comment: @AnPel, if you want to match from 6 to 20, replace the `+` with `{6,20}`.

Answer (score 1):

To allow only the mentioned characters in any string you can use the regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@'\-.#_]+$
```

Comment: One nit, in Perl 5 and Java, this will match `"a\n"` since `$` matches at the end or before a final line terminator.

Comment: It can accept empty. I not this. At least one charters contained that.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl::

```
$text =~ m/[a-z0-9@\'\-.#_]+/ig ;
```

Comment: Won't this match any password that contains at least one allowed character instead of matching only passwords that contain at least one allowed character and no disallowed characters?